# Show that the set $H= \{[0]_{10}, [5]_{10}\}$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_{10}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups

> Show that the set $H= \{[0]_{10}, [5]_{10}\}$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_{10}$.

Here is what I have currently. If $a,b \in H$, then since $H$ only contains two elements WLOG assume $a = [0]_{10}$ and $b=[5]_{10}$. Thus $a+b = [0]_{10} + [5]_{10} = [0+5]_{10} \in H$.

Now it seems that the identity is $[0]_{10}$ since for any $[h]_{10}$ we have that $[0]_{10} + [h]_{10} = [h]_{10}$.

I’m a bit stuck on how to show that for every $h \in H$, there exitst $h^{-1} \in H$. What is the inverse even for example for $[5]_{10}$?

Comment: What is $[5]_{10}+[5]_{10}$?

Comment: If you have a set of elements $\{0,k\}$, where $0$ is the identity element of the superGroup, then the issue is whether $k + k = 0$, within the superGroup.

Comment: Note that this subgroup is an additive group. So instead of $h^{-1}$ we write $-h$. And $-[5]_{10}$ is some x so that $[5]_{10} + x = [0]_{10}$.

Comment: We can't WLOG assume $a=[0]$ and $b=[5]$. Because we never assumed they were distinct. And we shouldn't assume they are distinct.

Comment: @Arthur Do you mean that $a$ could equal $b$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That would be $[0]_{10}$

Comment: Indeed. And therefore the inverse of $[5]_{10}$ is $[5]_{10}$.

Comment: I mean that you do have to check those cases as well, yes. For instance, $\{[0],[3]\}$ is _not_ a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_{10}$, because it's not closed under addition, but you have to use $a=b=[3]$ to see it.

Comment: @Arthur Re my first comment, checking whether $k + k = 0$ kills two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 1):

Since $H$ is a nonempty, finite subset of $\Bbb Z_{10}$, [it suffices to show that $H$ is closed under $+$, the operation of $\Bbb Z_{10}$.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Finite_Subgroup_Test)

To this end, simply observe the [Cayley table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table#:%7E:text=Named%20after%20the%2019th%20century,an%20addition%20or%20multiplication%20table.):

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
+ & [0]_{10} & [5]_{10} \\
\hline
[0]_{10} & [0]_{10} & [5]_{10} \\
[5]_{10} & [5]_{10} & [0]_{10}.
\end{array}$$

The inverse of $[5]_{10}$ is itself. This can be verified by direct computation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ then for every divisor of $10$, $G$ has a subgroup.
That is, Subgroups are $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, $2\mathbb{Z}_{10}$,$5\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ and $10\mathbb{Z}_{10}$

Let $H=5\mathbb{Z}_{10}=\{0,5\}$ under addition modulo $10$, then by 2 step subgroup test;

for all $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ clearly $a+_{10}b \in \mathbb{Z}_{10}$,

for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ , $a^{-1}\in \mathbb{Z}_{10}$,
In $H$, $0^{-1}=0 $ in $ \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ and $1^{-1}=1 $ in $ \mathbb{Z}_{10}$
Hence $H$ is a subgroup of $G=\mathbb{Z}_{10}$, and simliary one can proof for other subgroups also.